# "Undefined Reference" installing RMySQL on Windows 7

Tags: r, rmysql

Running R3.1, Rtools 3.1 on Windows 7 Professional.

> Sys.getenv('MYSQL_HOME')
>   [1] "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6"

When I execute:
install.packages("RMySQL", type = "source")

I get a long list of error messages:

```
RS-MySQL.o:RS-MySQL.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `mysql_more_results@4'
RS-MySQL.o:RS-MySQL.c:(.text+0x348): undefined reference to `mysql_init@4'
RS-MySQL.o:RS-MySQL.c:(.text+0x365): undefined reference to `mysql_options@12'
:
:
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RMySQL'
```

I have copied C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib/libmysql.dll to C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin, and created C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib/opt folder and copied C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib/libmysql.lib to the opt folder in order to get this far.

I have tried this with both MySQL 5.5 and 5.6, same results.

Comment: Is that the exact path? Is this a 64-bit OS?

Comment: Ollie: Thanks for the nudge! Problem solved!

64-bit OS, 64-bit MySQL, but RStudio was running the 32-bit version of R. Had RStudio switch over to 64-bit R, and RMySQL installed fine.

Thanks,
     Mike